# left hand side eigenvector in python?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, eigenvector

How do calculate the left hand side eigenvector in python?

```
    >>> import from numpy as np
    >>> from scipy.linalg import eig
    >>> np.set_printoptions(precision=4)
    >>> T = np.mat("0.2 0.4 0.4;0.8 0.2 0.0;0.8 0.0 0.2")
    >>> print "T\n", T
    T
    [[ 0.2  0.4  0.4]
     [ 0.8  0.2  0. ]
     [ 0.8  0.   0.2]]
    >>> w, vl, vr = eig(T, left=True)
    >>> vl
    array([[ 0.8165,  0.8165,  0.    ],
           [ 0.4082, -0.4082, -0.7071],
           [ 0.4082, -0.4082,  0.7071]])
```

This does not seem correct, google has not been kind on this!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your result is correct to my understanding.

However, you might be misinterpreting it. The [numpy docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html) are a bit clearer on what the left eigenvectors should be.

> Finally, it is emphasized that v consists of the right (as in
>   right-hand side) eigenvectors of a. A vector y satisfying dot(y.T, a)
>   = z * y.T for some number z is called a left eigenvector of a, and, in general, the left and right eigenvectors of a matrix are not
>   necessarily the (perhaps conjugate) transposes of each other.

I.e. you need to transpose the vectors in `vl`. `vl[:,i].T` is the i-th left eigenvector.
If I test this, I get, that the results are correct.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy.linalg import eig
>>> np.set_printoptions(precision=4)
>>> T = np.mat("0.2 0.4 0.4;0.8 0.2 0.0;0.8 0.0 0.2")
>>> print "T\n", T
T
[[ 0.2  0.4  0.4]
 [ 0.8  0.2  0. ]
 [ 0.8  0.   0.2]]
>>> w, vl, vr = eig(T, left=True)
>>> vl
array([[ 0.8165,  0.8165,  0.    ],
       [ 0.4082, -0.4082, -0.7071],
       [ 0.4082, -0.4082,  0.7071]])
>>> [ np.allclose(np.dot(vl[:,i].T, T), w[i]*vl[:,i].T) for i in range(3) ]
[True, True, True]
```

Comment: Thanks Lemming, a question; I was told to scale my lsh eigenvector by >>> s =vl[:,1]/sum(vl[:,1])
>>> s
array([  7.3543e+15,  -3.6772e+15,  -3.6772e+15]). how do I convert the scientific notation into something recognizable and why am I scaling it. Thanks! Chris

Comment: @ChrisRigano I'm actually not quite sure, why you would want to scale the eigenvector like this. Because, if you look closely, you'll see, that the sum is nearly zero, hence the result of this scaling is not going to be very meaningful. If you meant to do `s=vl[:,1]/sqrt(sum(vl[:,1]**2))`, then you would be normalizing your eigenvector (I.e. making it a vector of length 1). Note, that the eigenvectors given by `eig` are already normalized.

Comment: @ChrisRigano Also note, that `numpy` already comes with a `norm` function `numpy.linalg.norm(vl[:,1])` returns 1.0. You can also read more about the scaling of eigenvectors [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Eigenspace_and_spectrum)

Comment: @ChrisRigano As for the scientific notation. There is `set_printoptions(suppress=True)`, but that only suppresses the scientific notation for small numbers. I don't know how to make numpy suppress it for large numbers. However, you could do something like this `', '.join('%.4f'%x for x in s)` and just print it manually. However, whether this is more or less readable is arguable.

Comment: You rock Lemming! On the scale, I need to use a lhs unit vector so I was trying to scale the sum of the vector to 1 (I never used a unit vector before, but that is my guess at one is) I am posting another that involves vector matrix multiplication. I hope I am lucky enough to get you on that one! Any book suggestions are welcome! I owe U mate! This has been answered.

Comment: @ChrisRigano I'm glad I could help. Btw, if you feel this answers your question, don't forget to click the green check-mark to the left of the answer. 

About the book. I liked "Jänich, Lineare Algebra". Unfortunately, that's in German, though. I suggest you go to the closest universities library and look through the linear algebra section. Pick one that you feel comfortable reading. That should get you started. And while you're there you could just as well ask one of the students around for a recommendation. All the best!

Comment: No green box! You answered it!

Comment: Found green box! please look out for other related posts in last 2 days.